# Parallelizing a 1D matrix multiplication using OpenMP

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm new to OpenMP and I'm trying to parallelize a 1D matrix multiplication (only multiplying the upper triangle of the matrix). My solution now is fast, but it's currently only using approximately half of the available threads, so I'm supposed to further parallelize it but I don't know where to start (I know saving data in the result array is the most time consuming, this array is external and can only save data into it).

This is the code (I'm multiplying and transposing at once):

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
#pragma omp for
for (int j=0; j < ny; ++j){
    for (int i=0; i < ny; ++i){
        if (i < j){
            continue;
        }
        double mat_mul_sum{0.};
        for (int k=0; k < nx; ++k){
             double mat_mul = new_data[k + j*nx] * new_data[k + i*nx];
             mat_mul_sum += mat_mul;
        }
        array_results[i + j*ny] = mat_mul_sum;
    }
}
}
```

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the sizes of nx, ny and nz?
I had mixed results with [collapsing loops](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/openmp-loop-collapse-directive.html). In general as far as performance goes I'd try to get rid of the `if` and see if there is a way of making the data accesses more contiguous in memory.
Sadly I will only have time to have a closer look at it tomorrow...

Comment: @2b-t collapsing loops will not solve the load-balancing issue and should also introduces a small unwanted overhead here. One can tune the schedule to mitigate the load-balancing issue, but it is better to do it manually when it is possible as dynamic schedule also introduces a significant overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can start by removing the `continue` in the loop and **start the `i`-based loop at the value `j`**. Then, you can focus on the load-balancing issue between the threads.

One simple solution to **balance the work between threads** is to work simultaneously on the beginning and the end of the matrix (in each thread). Visually, it is like cutting a corner of the triangle and moving it to form a rectangle of size `ny x (ny/2)`. Note that the case where `ny` is odd should be carefully considered (as the shape will not be a pure rectangle).

Finally, you can optimize the `k`-loop using an **SIMD reduction**.

Here is what the resulting code should look like (untested):

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp for
    for (int j=0; j < (ny+1)/2; ++j)
    {
        const int jUp = j;
        const int jDown = ny - 1 - j;

        for (int i=jUp; i < ny; ++i)
        {
            double mat_mul_sum{0.};
            #pragma omp simd reduction(+:mat_mul_sum)
            for (int k=0; k < nx; ++k){
                 double mat_mul = new_data[k + jUp*nx] * new_data[k + i*nx];
                 mat_mul_sum += mat_mul;
            }
            array_results[i + jUp*ny] = mat_mul_sum;
        }

        // Compute the center only once
        if(jUp != jDown)
        {
            for (int i=jDown; i < ny; ++i)
            {
                double mat_mul_sum{0.};
                #pragma omp simd reduction(+:mat_mul_sum)
                for (int k=0; k < nx; ++k){
                     double mat_mul = new_data[k + jDown*nx] * new_data[k + i*nx];
                     mat_mul_sum += mat_mul;
                }
                array_results[i + jDown*ny] = mat_mul_sum;
            }
        }
    }
}
```